# Inconsistent conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I have a specification range that I want the conditional formatting code to reference and fill the cell with a color (or no color) if the value is out of the specification range. It works with some numbers and not all numbers. For example, if the lowspec range is set to 305 and 305 is inputted into the data cell, it gets highlighted RED as out of spec when it should not be. But if the lowspec range is 299 and 299 is inputted, it does not get highlighted which is exactly what I want. This goes the same with the highspec also.

Keep in mind my lowspec/highspec ranges are being pulled via vlookup so I'm not sure if that's creating the issue?

Hopefully all of this makes sense.

Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim lowspec As Double, highspec As Double

Dim width As Range

Dim C As Range

lowspec = Me.Range("l6")
highspec = Me.Range("p6")


Set width = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("i16:o101"))

Application.EnableEvents = False
 If Not width Is Nothing Then

    For Each C In width.Cells
       v = C.Value
       If Len(v) > 0 Then
           Select Case v
               Case Is < lowspec: newcolor = 3
               Case Is > highspec: newcolor = 45
           End Select
       Else
           newcolor = xlNone
       End If
       C.Interior.ColorIndex = newcolor
    Next C
 End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Just for more context, is there a specific reason you went with VBA as opposed to regular conditional formatting?

Comment: If i use the excel conditional formatting, it fills my empty cells with the highlighted color until data is inputted. At least that's my experience with some of my other forms using it.

Comment: You should be able to avoid that with conditional formatting...

Comment: I tried "Using a formula to determine which cells to format" with the formula =And($I$16:$O$101<>"",$I$16:$O$101<$L$6) and it doesn't fill the cells but it also never highlights the cell if its out of spec. What is your suggestion?

Comment: `=AND(I16<>"",I16<$L$6)`. The rule should apply to the range `$I$16:$O$101`.

Comment: I second @BigBen With normal conditional formatting and applying the said rules, it works.  Personally, I prefer to use the following formula =IF(A1<$L$6,1,0) because I can control whether the formatting is triggered or not by the condition by simply switching the 1 and 0.

Comment: @BigBen, that works! Thanks.

Comment: Update, same thing is happening as my macros...

Comment: Are the lowspec/highspec values perhaps *text-that-looks-like-a-number*?

Comment: its a vlookup formula, however the cell is formatted as a number.